# Sending POST request with form-urlencoded parameters in AngularJS using ngResource

Tags: angularjs, header, content-type, angular-resource, ngresource

I am trying to do a POST request with ngResources in AngularJS, I want to send my parameters in url and I have changed `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },` in `$save` method in `ngResources`. The request goes out with the correct content type, but the data goes as a JSON. Is there any standard way to overcome this problem?

The factory

```
.factory('Token', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://myProject/token/ ', { }, {
            save: {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }
        });
    }])
```

The calling function

```
.service('tokenService', ['$http', 'Token',
        function ($http, Token) {

            this.getToken = function () {
                var t = new Token()
                t.name = 'myName';
                t.password = '78457'

                return t.$save();
            };
        }])
```